# Automatically change home page

Tags: homepage

I am using a static page as my homepage. I would like to be able to create a new version of the homepage and add it to some kind of publication queue so the new version gets published at midnight. How would I achieve this?

Comment: show link:-http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-homepage-in-wordpress/

Comment: Hi lorenzo, please [take the tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and read about [what is considered "on topic" on WP StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe this will help you to formulate a question that will actually get answered. Important things to add to your question: your current code, what have you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this plugin: [Front Page Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/front-page-scheduler/)

> Front Page Scheduler let you choose some page to be shown as the front page of your site during a specific daily period, in specific week days. Since version 0.1.4, you can even create a set of “rules”, choosing specific front pages for different days and perio